# SQL Command to calculate difference between 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am not very competent in Oracle SQL and I have been assigned with this task. I want to find previous records with the same id and calculate the difference between their table_values. What I have done so far is a select that shows the previous value where it exists, however I cannot calculate the difference and I get syntax errors on my queries. I have tried to SELECT *,TABLE_VALUE-PREVIOUS_VALUE but apparently i am phrasing it wrong. All help appreciated!

My Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM( 
SELECT
    TABLE_ID,
    TABLE_VALUE,
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
LAG(TOWER_VALUE) OVER (
        PARTITION BY TABLE_ID
        ORDER BY YEAR,MONTH) PREVIOUS_VALUE
FROM
    MY_TABLE)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.  You can use:

```
select t.*,
       (tower_value -
        lag(tower_value) over (partition by table_id order by year, month)
       ) as diff
from my_table t;
```

If you do use a subquery, you need to qualify the `*`.  So, in your case:

```
select t.*,
       (value - previous_value) as diff
from ( . . . 
     ) t;
```

In other words, Oracle treats `select *` as complete `select` clause.  You can't add anything else to it.  In order to do what you want, you need to *qualify* the `*` and then you can add additional columns.

Comment: Wow that is a super helpful not only answer but explanation of the Oracle select query that provided me with an understanding I didn't previously have. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesTheProg . . . I recommend (in general) qualifying column names and `*`, but I think Oracle is the only database that has this limitation.